# JavaScript not working sentences

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php program which is suppose to alert the links clicked.For example I have a link `hello` and when I click on that link javascript should alert `hello`. It works fine without spaces, but when I have a link like `hello world` it does not alert anything.These words are extracted form a database.

My code is given below

```
function gmail(val)
{
    alert(val);
}
```

For php

```
<?php
    $name="raj"; //this is just a dummy value
    $include "database_connectivity.php";
    $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$database_username,$database_password);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Could not connect to database.'.odbc_error());
    }
    $select="SELECT WHERE_TO_CHANGE FROM REQUEST_SEND_TABLE WHERE SENT_FROM ='$name'";
    $exe=odbc_exec($conn, $select);
    if(!$exe)
    {
        die("Could not execute query".odbc_error());
    }
    while($row_user=odbc_fetch_array($exe))
    {
        $show=$row_user['WHERE_TO_CHANGE'];
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$show."' value='".$show."'>";
        echo "<a href='#' id='check'  onClick='gmail(".$show.".value)' >".$show."            </a>";
        echo"<br>";
    }
    odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here ?

Comment: Try it without the database connection to debug this. Heck, try it even without PHP, just pure HTML & Javascipt.

Comment: why are you showing PHP code for HTML issue? show the generated HTML.

Comment: I'd also suggest checking out the javascript that you end up with on the rendered html page. Looking at that should make it easier to find the error.

Comment: Spaces aren't allowed in IDs, that may be causing problems with those `<input>` elements.

Comment: @Barmar you were right i tried with without database spaces were definitely the issuse

Comment: pass the value as a string. i think doing this u could get the result

Comment: @NullPointer because all the connection are done form `odbc_*` where i work.

Comment: @kmkaplan tried it and spaces were the issue

Comment: The problem is with `gmail(foo bar.value)`. That's not valid JS syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row_user=odbc_fetch_array($exe))
{
    $show=$row_user['WHERE_TO_CHANGE'];
    $show_nospace = str_replace(' ', '_', $show);
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$show_nospace."' value='".$show."'>";
    echo "<a href='#' id='check'  onClick='gmail(".$show_nospace.".value)' >".$show."            </a>";
    echo"<br>";
}
```

And if `$show` can contain other characters that aren't allowed in IDs, you'll need to replace them as well. You'll also need to escape any quotes when using it in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

in your onclick event, change it to this:

```
gmail(document.getElementById($show).value)
```

it might be better to do that in your function though and just pass in the id:

```
gmail($show)
```

That way you can check the existence of the element first before trying to call .value on it.

Comment: It's still not working for spaces @barmar said spaces were the issue

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes when ever there is a space

onClick="gmail('".$show_nospace.".value');"

see the single quotes ('test test')

Comment: Strings don't have a `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$show."' value='".$show."'>";
    echo "<a href='#' id='check'  onClick='gmail(".$show.")' >".$show."</a>";
```

instead of:

```
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$show."' value='".$show."'>";
    echo "<a href='#' id='check'  onClick='gmail(".$show.".value)' >".$show."</a>";
```